# How can I mute the snapped TV app on the Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

I want to have my cable tv snapped on the right side of my screen, but I want it muted - while the main screen application unmuted.   How can I do this?    I have the option to do this with Twitch snapped, but I cannot find where / how to do this in the snapped tv application.

Comment: Does your cable have a mute button?

Comment: No.   Only the TV does

Comment: currently you can't control the volume of snapped applications. This may change in futre system updates though, so keep that in mind.

Comment: If you can change the audio output on your cable box to be something other than HDMI, it may be possible. I've yet to try it on mine, but either way, not a real ideal thing to have to do every time you want to mute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now control volume of the snapped app and main app separately, thanks to an update in the Xbox One OS since this question was asked.

In Main settings>Display & sound>Sound mixer you can also set the relative volume of the two audio sources.